# Copy Constructor const char* and Shared_ptr

Tags: c++, constructor, shared-ptr

I have a class `Keywords`:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
class Keywords
{
    public:
        ///Constructor
        Keywords(const char*,vector<shared_ptr<RegularExpression>>,vector<string>);
        Keywords(const Keywords& other);
    private:
        const char * xmlFile;
        vector<shared_ptr<RegularExpression>> vreg;
        vector<string> sw;
}
```

And I want to construct a copy Constructor for `const char*` and `vector<shared_ptr<RegularExpression>>`

Am I coding it correctly?

```
Keywords::Keywords(const Keywords& other):xmlFile(new char[100]),vreg(other.vreg.size())
{
    strcpy((char*)xmlFile, (char*)other.xmlFile);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < other.vreg.size(); ++i)
        vreg[i] = shared_ptr<RegularExpression>(new RegularExpression(*other.vreg[i]));
}
```

From What i understand I make a copy The Const char* and the vector of shared_ptr.

Thank you.

***So After the removal of const char * i'll have***

```
class Keywords
{
    public:
        ///Constructor
        Keywords(string,vector<shared_ptr<RegularExpression>>,vector<string>);
        Keywords(const Keywords& other);
    private:
        string xmlFile;
        vector<shared_ptr<RegularExpression>> vreg;
        vector<string> sw;
}
```

and the copy constructor would be:

```
Keywords::Keywords(const Keywords& other):vreg(other.vreg.size()),sw(other.sw)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < other.vreg.size(); ++i)
        vreg[i] = shared_ptr<RegularExpression>(new RegularExpression(*other.vreg[i]));
}
```

Destcrutor:

```
Keywords::~Keywords()
{
    sw.clear();
    vreg.erase(vreg.begin());
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::string` instead of the `char*`? The compiler generated copy members would be correct.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about it. Yes that's true. Instead of this

Comment: And there is implicit conversion for `char const *` to `std::string`, so you could call your constructor the same way

Comment: string x = "test";
const char * y = x.c_str();
yes it's c_str()

Comment: Concerning the other part, the vector of shared_ptr is it being copied correctly?

Comment: Good job on vector of smart pointer!

Comment: Yes, you're copying the vector correctly, assuming you don't want the copies to share the same `RegularExpression` objects.  Do you not want to copy the `sw`  vector too?

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely
Yes i would like to see an example if it's possible. Just trying to manage the memory.

Comment: What do u mean by **assuming you don't want the copies to share the** **same RegularExpression objects**

Comment: Using `shared_ptr` would allow several objects to share ownership of the same `RegularExpression`, but you are not sharing ownership because your copy constructor creates new `RegularExpression` objects for the new `Keywords` object. If that's what you want, you've written it correctly.

Comment: To copy the `sw` vector just add `sw(other.sw)` to the member initializers in the constructor.

Comment: Since your members are now all managed types (`string` and `vector`), you don't need to define a custom destructor to clear them, the default destructor is good enough and will handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here. The one you probably want to use is the *compiler-provided default copy constructor:*

```
class Keywords {
    std::string xmlFile;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<RegularExpression>> vreg;
    std::vector<std::string> sw;

public:
    Keywords(const char *xmlFile,
             const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<RegularExpression>>& vreg,
             const std::vector<std::string>& sw)
      : xmlFile(xmlFile), vreg(vreg), sw(sw) {}

    // Look, Ma, no special member functions!
};
```

In this context, the default copy constructor will do exactly what you (most likely) want: it will make a copy of the `vreg` vector, which means copying the *shared_ptr* elements of the vector — but not deep-copying the *RegularExpression* objects themselves! You (most likely) don't want to deep-copy those objects, because they're expensive to copy, and I would guess that it's just as appropriate to use the originals as to use copies. Normally you'd have to worry about memory management — whose job is it to free the originals now that two different `Keywords` objects claim to own them? — but in this case that's 100% solved, because the two `Keywords` objects will *share* ownership. That's what `shared_ptr` *does*.

This is a great example of what's known as **The Rule of Zero**. The familiar Rule of Three (or Five, or maybe Six) says that if you define one special member function, you should define them all. The Rule of Zero says that *you shouldn't define **any** special member functions* unless you're doing something really tricksy.

---

If you *want* to be tricksy here, and write a custom copy-constructor that *does* do deep copies of the `RegularExpression` elements,

...well, you should ask yourself why you're not just using `std::vector<RegularExpression> vreg` in the first place — then you could still use the Rule of Zero, because the default copy-constructor would make deep copies for you just as you apparently want.

But if you are *unshakeable* in your desire to do tricksy things, you'd do it like this:

```
class Keywords {
    std::string xmlFile;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<RegularExpression>> vreg;
    std::vector<std::string> sw;

public:
    Keywords(const char *xmlFile,
             const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<RegularExpression>>& vreg,
             const std::vector<std::string>& sw)
      : xmlFile(xmlFile), vreg(vreg), sw(sw) {}

    Keywords(const Keywords& rhs)
      : xmlFile(rhs.xmlFile), sw(rhs.sw)
    {
        vreg.reserve(rhs.vreg.size());
        for (auto&& sptr : rhs.vreg) {
            vreg.emplace_back(std::make_shared<RegularExpression>(*sptr));
        }
    }

    // Don't forget to implement copy-assignment too!
    // I'm just going to delete it here to keep anyone from using it.
    //
    Keywords& operator= (const Keywords&) = delete;
};
```

This implementation might *still* not do what you want; for example, if before the copy operation we have `rhs.vreg[0] == rhs.vreg[1]`, our constructor will quietly make two copies of that single `RegularExpression` object, and give us a new `Keywords` object `*this` such that `this->vreg[0] != this->vreg[1]`. This is merely a specific application of the general principle that it's hard to make a copy of an arbitrary pointer graph.

Did you notice how long this line of code is?

```
    vreg.emplace_back(std::make_shared<RegularExpression>(*sptr));
```

That's a red flag in normal C++11 code. In normal code, we don't have to write explicit types like `RegularExpression`; the compiler can just infer the types. If I wanted to copy `sptr`, I could just write `vreg.emplace_back(sptr)` — no explicit types! But here I had to write out `std::make_shared<RegularExpression>(...)`. This is awkward... *because I'm **Doing It Wrong**.* It's not *normal* to take a `shared_ptr`, dereference it, copy-construct the thing *pointed to by* the `shared_ptr`, and then re-wrap that in a new `shared_ptr` with different ownership. That's a complicated and bizarre operation, and so it kind of makes sense that the syntax to do it in C++11 is complicated and bizarre.

I recommend *not* being tricksy, in this instance. :)